# Query Max/Min value shows original values

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm taking the max value and min value of a table composed of Date, Time, and Load.  For example:

```
Date      |   Time         |   Temp
-------------------------------------
1/1/2014  |   09:00:00 AM  |  100
-------------------------------------
1/1/2014  |   09:01:00 AM  |  110
-------------------------------------
1/1/2014  |   09:02:00 AM  |  120
-------------------------------------
1/1/2014  |   09:03:00 AM  |  111
-------------------------------------
```

....................And so on

I've tried to just use the functions Min(), Max() but these values output the same data as the original table.  See SQL code:

```
SELECT Table1.Date, Table1.Time, Min(Table1.Temp) AS MinLoad
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Date, Table1.Time;
```

I tried using DMin() and DMax() functions but instead of getting a value I got a null of the values.  I tried the syntax

```
DMin("[Temp]", "[Table1]", [Time] Between #09:00# And #15:00#)
```

I'm fairly new to Access so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just used it for reference, updated to show NumVal

Comment: NumVal is hardly any better!!

Comment: Your problem is that your data is unique with respect to `Date` and `Time`, so having it group by those columns yields the single result (as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT Date.DateLog, Min(Table1.Data) AS MinOfData
FROM [Date] INNER JOIN Table1 ON Date.DateLog = Table1.Date
GROUP BY Date.DateLog;
```